# NoClassDefFoundError during project import of linkki-tutorial in Eclipse

Tags: linkki

I generated the project using the command line as described at https://linkki-framework.org/tutorial/02_project_setup/index.html - but when I import it in Eclipse (using "Existing maven project"), I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.JarArchiver
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$ReflectiveProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:126)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:98)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:93)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1050)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1050)
at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusRequirements$RequirementProvider.get(PlexusRequirements.java:250)
at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52)
at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:160)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:124)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:98)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:93)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1050)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1050)
at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.getConfiguredMojo(MavenImpl.java:354)
at org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.reflectManifestGeneration(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:469)
at org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.generateManifest(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:422)
at org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.mavenProjectChanged(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:227)
at org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator$1.build(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:167)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:135)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:169)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$1(MavenBuilder.java:114)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:114)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$0(MavenBuilder.java:105)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:153)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:101)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:88)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:197)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:832)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:371)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:392)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

I use Java 11 (openjdk) and Eclipse 20.9 (4.17.0) on Windows. I tried to find a solution by myself, but all the articles referred to stuff like "use maven-jar-plugin" which is already in the pom.xml

And it seems to be a Java-11-problem - when I use Java 8, all works fine :-/

Comment: Hi @thorsten, have you tried updating the maven-jar-plugin's version (the latest is 3.2.0; 3.0.2 should work as well, but maybe your repository has some errors and downloading a different version might work faster then removing old artefacts) or checking which Maven version your Eclipse uses (Window->Preferences->Maven->Installations and ~Maven->User Settings)?

Comment: @thorsten I don't think this is linkki related, seems to be a problem of eclipse m2e in combination with the configured maven plugins.